# You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router> but Im in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Route inside `BrowserRouter` but still getting error, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App/index';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import reducer from './store/reducer';
import config from './config';

const store = createStore(reducer);

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename={config.basename}>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? Also, without seeing the contents of your App component, which I assume holds your routes, it's hard to debug.

Comment: Post your `App` component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `withRouter()` like this.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Something));
```

this [document](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#redux-integration) may be helpful to you